# .gitignore and Visual Studio project: Ignore bin/Debug directory but not bin/Release directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, git, gitignore

I have a C# Visual Studio project in a git repository. I want to ignore the contents `bin/Debug` directory but not the contents of the `bin/Release`' directory. I've added `bin/Debug` to my `.gitignore` file, but it doesn't seem to work - it is including the entire contents of the `bin` directory. What would the correct entry be to do this?

Comment: show us your `.gitignore` file please

Comment: add 'Debug/' to your .gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this by replacing `bin/Debug` with `Debug`.

This would also have the affect of ignoring the `obj/Debug` directory, however I want to ignore the entire contents of the `obj` directory, so I have also added `obj` to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 98):

You shouldn't have to delete anything.  After you added the .gitignore file, run this command to clear the cache, then stage and commit again:

```
git rm -r . --cached
```

Comment: Note *then stage and commit again*

Comment: Yeah, if you were late to the party with your gitignore, then this is the correct solution to follow... when you stage and commit again, all of the bin/obj stuff that was committed before will be removed. Works a treat.

Comment: for me it worked only after I used a forced clear: 

git rm -r . --cached -f

Comment: This command marked all files in repository as removed.

Comment: Perfect answer!!!

Comment: git rm -r . --cached -f  this also work for me too

Comment: This is okay when you are at the beginning of a project! Otherwise files are removed and history lost! @KliverMax is right!

Answer (score 53):

This typically happens because the .gitignore was added after the files were committed. The .gitignore tells git to ignore untracked files that match, once stuff is committed the ignore will no longer work. One way to fix it is to remove the bin/debug folder (manually through explorer/powershell/bash), then commit the removals. Once that is done the ignores should work as you expect.

1. Remove files/folder
2. `git add -A`
3. `git commit`

Comment: Ah yes!  Thank you, this issue has eluded me for far longer than I'd like to admit.

Answer (score 48):

Here's what we've been using lately, it removes all resharper generated stuff and some other important things. Note that we don't commit our release directory, so you shouldn't include `Release/` in your `.gitignore`, but to answer your question, you should include `Debug/`.

```
/build/
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*/
*.sdf
bin/
obj/
Debug/
Release/
*.opensdf
*.tlog
*.log
TestResult.xml
*.VisualState.xml
Version.cs
Version.h
Version.cpp
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a pretty comprehensive example from github:

- https://github.com/github/gitignore
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Comment: This probably won't work due to the `bin/` ignore directive making `Debug/` and `Release/` redundant.

Comment: @Gary.S, it should still work. The latter lines are just redundant and could be removed.

Answer (score 23):

Running the following command worked for me (thanks to "orourkedd"):

```
git rm -r . --cached
```

I manually added the `.gitignore` file but it wasn't taken into consideration until I ran this command.

I then had to commit again and all good to go now. `/bin` and `/obj` folders are properly excluded now.

Answer (score 21):

I know it is an old question, but I've decided to share my approach which excludes exactly bin/Debug, bin/Release etc.

```
*/**/bin/Debug
*/**/bin/Release
*/**/obj/Debug
*/**/obj/Release
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
*.exe
*.pdb
*.manifest
*.cache
```

If you are using GitHub Desktop as I am using it, you can just right click the file you want to exclude or right click it and exclude by extension:

[image]

This will automatically generate a `.gitignore` file for you with the code like above. You can download GitHub Desktop here: [GitHub Desktop for Windows 64-bit](https://desktop.github.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This may be slightly off topic, but whenever starting to create a new project, I usually use [GitIgnore.IO](https://www.gitignore.io/) for creating my initial gitignore file and then I tweek it from there according to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on those file names you want to ignore from "Git Desktop", then add them to `.gitignore` file. Here gitignore file will be automatically created. Check in that file to git.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
/YourProjectNameFolder/bin/Debug
```